# using WCF service in mvc with csla

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, csla

I have a WCF service Provided by csla. I want to consume this service in my MVC Project.I have create a object of service like below:

```
ClientServiceReference.WcfPortalClient obj =
    new ClientServiceReference.WcfPortalClient();

obj.Open();

Csla.Core.ContextDictionary con = new Csla.Core.ContextDictionary();

var ClientType = client.GetType();

ClientCriteria criteria = new ClientCriteria { LoweredSubdomainName = hostname };

Csla.Server.Hosts.WcfChannel.FetchRequest request =
    new Csla.Server.Hosts.WcfChannel.FetchRequest(ClientType, criteria,con);
var list = obj.Fetch(request);
```

Getting error as:

> The best overloaded method match for       `Customer.ClientServiceReference.WcfPortalClient.Fetch(Csla.Server.Hosts.WcfChannel.FetchRequest)` has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

That is because the [documentation](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/CSLA-Core/Csla/WcfPortalClient/M/Fetch) says that the `Fetch` method takes a `CriteriaRequest`. You provide it with a `FetchRequest`.

From the docs:

> Fetch(CriteriaRequest) (Method)
>
> Parameters
>   request
>
> Type: **CriteriaRequest**